# Zip of function returns

Tags: python, tuples, zip

`fun(x)` is function that returns 3 values `ret1, ret2, ret3`

I have this code example which shows me how to get the returns of 5 function calls sorted in to separate tuples of the returns :

`ret1, ret2, ret3 = zip(fun(0), fun(1), fun(2), fun(3), fun(4))`

I want to do this now for n function calls without explicitly stating the function call, like with

`[fun(x) for x in range(5)]`

I guess my problem is that I'm no expert of the zip functionality so help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to unpack that list comprehension to pass it to the zip function. This is how you do that (e.g. for 10 functions)

```
ret1, ret2, ret3 = zip(*(fun(x) for x in range(10)))
```

Comment: Works like a charm, I tried the same thing without the ```*``` operator and it didn't work would you explain to me what it does?

Comment: @sebko_iic It unpacks the argument list: https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Comment: Sure. In python, there are two special bits of syntax:  `*` and `**`. They unpack tuples and dicts respectively, which allows a function to receive a variable length list of arguments or keyword arguments respectively. In this case, zip accepts the former. Have a look at how the in-built function is written here: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#zip.